# How to sync return when using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback to create channel?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, wcf, synchronization

I need to create a WCF ChannelFactory on a separate thread. The problem I am facing now is that the variable `svc` doesn't always return a value:

```
   ...
   Dim svc As T = Nothing
   Dim svcft As New DuplexChannelFactory(Of T)(caller, ep)
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(Sub(obj) svc = svcft.CreateChannel()))
   ...
```

Most of the time `svc` will return a null value but sometimes it does return a good reference. What am I doing wrong?

I modified my code according to YK1's comment as bellow. it still doesn't solve the issue - the svc still doesn't always set:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    Sub()
        svc = svcft.CreateChannel()
    End Sub
).ContinueWith(
    Sub()
        svcft = Nothing
    End Sub
)
If svc Is Nothing Then
    Throw New Exception("Creating service reference failed.") '<== get the error here...
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a race condition. The line after `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` may or may not have correct value for `svc` based on how current thread and thread pool thread is scheduled. This is bad and we dont want to do it this way.

`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` is the old way running stuff on threadpool threads in fire and forget manner. You generally dont want to sync back from there (although you can using `events`, however, those are all blocking ways).

We don't want to block application threads anymore. So, comes in `Async/Await` and `TPL`.

Here is the way you can do it:

```
Async Function MyFuncAsync(Of T)() As Task
   ...
   Dim svc As T = Nothing
   Dim svcft As New DuplexChannelFactory(Of T)(caller, ep)
   svc = Await Task.Run(Funtion() svcft.CreateChannel())
   ...
End Function
```

If you are not on .NET 4.5 and dont want to use `async/await` you can use `TPL` API directly.

```
...
Dim svc As T = Nothing
Dim svcft As New DuplexChannelFactory(Of T)(caller, ep)
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    Sub() 
        svc = svcft.CreateChannel()
    End Sub
).ContinueWith(
    Sub(t) 
        `rest of code here
    End Sub
)
```

If your main thread is UI thread (WPF/Winforms), if you want to sync back on UI thread, then your continuation could be made to run on UI thread. (`async/await` above capture `syncdhronizationcontext` automatically).

```
...
Dim svc As T = Nothing
Dim svcft As New DuplexChannelFactory(Of T)(caller, ep)
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    Sub() 
        svc = svcft.CreateChannel()
    End Sub
).ContinueWith(
    Sub(t) 
        `rest of code here
    End Sub,
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
```

Comment: Thanks YK1 for the excelent input. You are right, I am on .Net 4. So I tried TPL solution you recommened. I think there are must still be something I am doing wrong - the variable svc is still not always set. Here is a simplified version of my code:  Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() svc = svcft.CreateChannel()).ContinueWith(Sub() svcft = Nothing)

Comment: I have updated my origional post to show my latest code. It still doesn't solve the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: I figured it out - since I need to use svc in the main thread, the .ContinueWith function wouldn't help. Soon as I change that to .Wait() it worked. Thank you so much YK1!

Comment: @user2434400: sorry for delayed reply. your updated question is incorrect. your `code which uses svc` should be inside the `ContinueWith` delegate- not outside it. Sure, `Wait()` will work, but then it blocks the main thread - you loose the advantage of creating object on background thread.